# Keyboard shortcut to select / switch between decks in anki

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, anki

In anki you can do pretty much everything with shortcuts. But one thing I could not find a shortcut for is selecting a particular deck from multiple decks in the decks window. I tried pushing all the direction keys as well as the tab button and their combinations with  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  and  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  but they don't work. It is good to be able to select a deck without using a mouse. Are you aware of such a shortcut (or if not, how to create one)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#keyboard-shortcuts):

> The "Study Deck" item in the Tools menu allows you to quickly switch
>   to a deck with the keyboard. You can trigger it with the / key. When
>   opened, it will display all of your decks and show a filter area at
>   the top. As you type characters, Anki will display only decks matching
>   the characters you type.